# Which warp charter to wrap strings

Tags: php, string

I am new in php,I know that i can wrap string wi single quotes`(')` or with double quotes`(")`.
what is the differnt and what is the best way to use?

Comment: Please at least attempt basic spelling. Seriously. This question is offensively lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your string in single quotes `(')` instead of double quotes `(")` is faster because PHP searches for variables inside "…" and not in '…', use this when you’re not using variables you need evaluating in your string.

Comment: What do you use to type those quotes? They're completely wrong :) but I'm curious how someone types those by accident.

Comment: @Evert: ISTR Windows has a global mode where you can set this. Though I've never found it. Of course Word has its own setting.

Comment: Faster isn't strictly accurate; even a string wrapped in '..' is parsed for escapes, so the speed difference between "..." and '...' is so small even your computer won't notice it